# When should I run queue/listen instead of queue/run?

Tags: tasks, cli, queue

**Definitions from the [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-queue.html#public-methods):**

- `queue/run`: runs all the queued-up jobs
- `queue/listen`: listens to
  the queue and runs new jobs

**Example case:**

The `runQueueAutomatically` config option is set to false, and a cron job is calling `queue/run` every minute: `/1 * * * * /path/to/project/root/craft queue/run`.

In this case:

- Should I run `queue/listen` instead of `queue/run`?
- Does calling a new
  `queue/run` when a `queue/run` job is potentially still in process,
  could caused queue issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `queue/run` - should be used if you're going to manually execute this command via a `cron` job or such, because it runs any pending queue jobs, then exits
- `queue/listen` - should be used if you want it to constantly poll (with a reasonable cooldown interval) for new jobs, and run them, because it runs a `listen` process that spawns a sub-process to run queue jobs as they come in

More here: [Robust queue job handling in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms)

Comment: Thank you! Why you didn't mention the `queue/run` cron job solution in your article? Are there downsides using it instead of setting up a service with systemd?

Comment: It's just a bit less elegant but it should work fine.